# CSV file to Histogram in R

Tags: r, csv, histogram

I'm a total newbie with R, and I'm trying to create a histogram (with value and frequency as the axises) from a csv file (just one row of values). Any idea how I can do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should really start to read some basic R manual... 
[CRAN](http://cran.r-project.org/) offers a lot of them (look into the Manuals and Contributed sections)

In any case:

```
setwd("path/to/csv/file")
myvalues <- read.csv("filename.csv")
hist(myvalues, 100) # Example: 100 breaks, but you can specify them at will
```

See the manual pages for those functions for more help (accessible through `?read.table`, `?read.csv` and `?hist`).

Comment: Thanks! I'm getting an error "Error in hist.default(myvalues, 100) : 'x' must be numeric". I tried converting myvalues to asnumeric but it doesn't seem to be working (gives error "Error in hist.default(myvalues) : invalid number of 'breaks'"). Any idea what's up?

Comment: Without a reproducible example (code + example data) it is hard to say what is going wrong. Please paste the output of `dput(myvalues)` into your question above.

Comment: Agree with @Paul, we really need an example of your data to say more.

Comment: you would need something like `hist(myvalues[,1])`

Answer (score 11):

I'm also an R newbie, and I ran into the same thing. I made two separate mistakes, actually, so I'll describe them both here.

**Mistake 1: Passing a frequency table to hist().** Originally I was trying to pass a frequency table to `hist()` instead of passing in the raw data. One way to fix this is to use the `rep()` ("replicate") function to explode your frequency table back into a raw dataset, as described here:

- [Creating a histogram using aggregated data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19939073/creating-a-histogram-using-aggregated-data)
- [Simple R (histogram) from counted csv file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20089824/simple-r-histogram-from-counted-csv-file)

Instead of that, though, I just decided to read in my original dataset instead of the frequency table.

**Mistake 2: Wrong data type.** My raw data CSV file contains two columns: `hostname` and `bookings` (idea is to count the number of bookings each host generated during some given time period). I read it into a table.

```
> tbl <- read.csv('bookingsdata.csv')
```

Then when I tried to generate a histogram off the second column, I did this:

```
> hist(tbl[2])
```

This gave me the "'x' must be numeric" error you mention in a comment. (It was trying to read the "bookings" column header in as a data value.)

This fixed it:

```
> hist(tbl$bookings)
```

Answer (score 4):

To plot the histogram, the values must be of numeric class i.e the data must be of numeric value. Here the value of x seems to be of some other class.

Run the following command and see:

```
sapply(myvalues[1,],class)
```