# Creating a histogram using aggregated data

Tags: r, csv, histogram

Embarrassingly simple question...

I'm new to R and I can't seem to wrap my head around this for some reason. I have a CSV file which looks something like this:

```
Bin,Number
1363,5
1028,4
1303,3
1467,1
1242,3
1415,5
..
.
```

The bin size is 1, with a range of 1000-1500. I have read my CSV file in, everything seems to be ok there, but I just cannot produce a simple histogram. I have tried simply using a barplot, but the data is not numerically ordered, so will not produce the output I need. Using data such as this, how can I produce a histogram in R?

Once I have a simple histogram, I'm sure I'll be able to play around with it and format it nicely.

Comment: I recommend you to read this tutorial: http://statmethods.net It is a good learning resource for R (I use it frequently).

Answer (score 6):

Because the `hist` function does the counting of items in each bin, you need to 'explode' your 'already counted' data, for example by using `rep`. Then you can use `hist` on the resulting vector.

```
with(df, hist(rep(x = Bin, times = Number)))
```

Comment: exploding the data works if you have a small enough data set, but taking aggregated data, expanding it to pass to hist, and then re-aggregating it is a lot of wasted memory and CPU and doesn't work for much larger datasets.  Better to use a function that accepts pre-aggregated data and constructs the histogram directly, such as `PreBinnedHistogram` from the [HistogramTools](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/HistogramTools) package on CRAN.

Answer (score 4):

While this is absolutely possible with base R, I always enjoy the elegance and simplicity of the package `ggplot2`.

For example, you could do the following:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data, aes(x=Bin, y=Number)) + geom_bar(stat='identity', width=1)
```

(Run `install.packages('ggplot2')` first, if you do not have the package installed.)

Answer (score 1):

Your data is already binned, and so the easiest way to get an R Histogram object from this data set is to use the `PreBinnedHistogram` function from the [HistogramTools](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/HistogramTools) package on CRAN.  This function takes a list of breakpoints (column 1 in your example) and counts of each bin (column 2) and returns a proper R histogram object for plotting or further analysis without first exploding your dataset into the unbinned form.

```
library(HistogramTools)
my.data<-read.csv("input.csv")
plot(PreBinnedHistogram(my.data$V1, my.data$V2))
```

Answer (score 0):

The key is to putting your data in the right order. Assuming your dataframe is called `df`:

```
barplot(df$Number[order(df$Bin)])
```

If you use `barplot` simply by feeding it your vector of data, it will draw the bars in the order of the vector. Using `order` puts them in their numeric order before plotting.

Comment: The problem with this solution is that it does create wrong results if bins are missing in the file (which could be fixed upfront, of course). Furthermore, you have some work to do to get the axis labeling nicely done.