# Simple R (histogram) from counted csv file

Tags: r, graph, histogram, frequency

HI Guys I'm trying to plot a frequency graph of a simple 2d file

```
file:data.csv
terms,count
1,10
5,17
3,28
9,30
```

I want the first col(terms) to be the x-axis and the col(count) be the height/percentage.

I've tried this:

```
d<-read.csv(data.csv)
hist(d)
Error in hist.default(d) : 'x' must be numeric
dc<-table(d)
hist(dc)  <-- wrong result.
```

Comment: that is crazy - I voted it up actually and apparently three user (accounts) voted it down - ridiculous

Comment: @Яaffael - Agree that the downvotes are unnecessary, it's a legitimate question, but already answered elsewhere

Comment: Still a mystery why `read.csv(data.csv)` was not the source of the error due to the file name being unquoted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that `hist()` needs a vector containing your objects as often as they are present in your data. Your are providing it a frequency table.

See this:

```
> df <- data.frame(obj = c(1,2,3,4,5), count = c(2,3,5,4,2))

> hist(df)
Error in hist.default(df) : 'x' must be numeric

> hist(rep(df$obj, df$count), breaks=0:5)
[img]

> rep(df$obj, df$count)
 [1] 1 1 2 2 2 3 3 3 3 3 4 4 4 4 5 5
```

[image]

`rep(a,n)` repeats element by element the value of `a` `n`-times. Then you have the vector you need and you can hand it to `hist()`.

Comment: You might be interested to know that no error is thrown with your first two lines of code on R 3.0.2 running on a Mac.

Comment: The error does appear on R 2.15.1 in 32 bit WinXP.

Answer (score 1):

```
d<-read.csv(text="terms,count
1,10
5,17
3,28
9,30")

hist(d)   # No error ... but not the plot you wanted.
```

Your lack of quotes around `data.csv` could be the problem or if the the first line in the file is really `file:data.csv`, that could be another problem. It does appear, however, that you probably want `barchart` or `barplot`, since you have already done the aggregation of the counts.

To illustrate why barchart or barplot *could* have been use:

```
require(lattice)
# dividing by total "counts" to get the fractional values
 barchart(count/sum(d$count)~factor(terms), data=d)
```

[image]

Comment: Hi file:data is not the firstline no. barchart and barplot still gives wrong results. I want to have a "bar-like" graph with terms(1,5,3,9) as the x-axis and the counts on the Y-axis with the percentage ?

Comment: that is actually not the problem in this case

Comment: I've got to agree with @Яaffael - `hist(d)` will give an error, you can't pass `hist` a dataframe

Comment: The statement that you cannot pass a dataframe to `hist` is incorrect. If the columns are all 'numeric' you will get a separate histogram for each column.